# php find out 2nd match

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to grab a few images from a site but have got stumped due to different file extensions...

I have 2 matches in preg_match_all()

```
if (preg_match_all('~http://foo.com/foo_(.*?).(.*?)~i', $returned_content, $matches)) {
```

1st is img name and 2nd is img extension and would like to work out what each extension is so I can use it later in the code:

**Update, full code:**

```
       //cURL function here get_data()

 $returned_content = get_data('http://foo.com/page/2');

        if (preg_match_all('~http://foo.com/foo_(.*?)\.(.*?)~i', $returned_content, $matches)) {

   foreach ($matches[1] as $key) {

    $file = 'http://foo.com/foo_' . $key . 'correct extension';// Need to have correct extension here
        echo '<img src="' . $file . '" alt="" />';
           }
        }
```

Comment: I assume you want to make that a literal `.` by escaping it thus: `\.`?

Comment: you might want to read the HTML into an HTML parser and select the value of the img src. regexes aren't really the best way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$returned_content = "sdfasdfsdfshttp://foo.com/foo_sdfsdfsdf.fdfdsf";
preg_match_all('~http\://foo\.com/foo_(.*?)\.(.*?)$~i', $returned_content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Returns

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://foo.com/foo_sdfsdfsdf.fdfdsf
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => sdfsdfsdf
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => fdfdsf
    )

)
```

Unless : and . are in character blocks [], : and . are used as modifiers, they must be escaped.

Comment: `:` has no special meaning here, so there's no need to escape it.